# Play and Stop sound file according a particular condition checked every 2 secs with java

Tags: java, audio, mp3

I consume a service every 2 secs and according its response I want to play or stop a WAVE sound.
All seems to work fine (except the overlap of several WAVE executions => but this is not the principal problem), but I cannot stop all the music when condition happens and i don't understand why.

These are my classes

musicStuff.java

```
package hello;

import java.applet.AudioClip;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineEvent;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineListener;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class musicStuff implements AudioClip{

    private Clip clip;
    
    void playMusic(String musicLocation) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader()
                    .getResourceAsStream(musicLocation);
            AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inputStream);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(audioStream);
            clip.start();
            
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException | IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error occured during playback process:" + ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
    
    @Override
     public void stop() {
        if (clip == null)
            return;
        clip.stop();
        clip.close();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void loop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void play() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

}
```

HelloWord.java

```
package hello;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String audioFilePath = "AudioFileWithWavFormat.wav";

        Timer mytimer = new Timer();
        musicStuff player = new musicStuff();
        final TimerTask mytask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                RestRequest example = new RestRequest();
                String response;
                try {
                    response = example.run("https://webservice.url");
                    if (response.length() > 2) {
                        System.out.println("Yes start play music"); 
                        player.playMusic(audioFilePath);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Stop all played music");
                        player.stop();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        int delay = 2;
        mytimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mytask, delay, delay);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fixed this problem with this code

musicStuff.java

```
package hello;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;

public class musicStuff {

    FileInputStream fileInputStream;
    BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
    
    Thread playThread;
    RestRequest example = new RestRequest();
    int flag_start = 0;
    int flag_stop = 0;
    long totalLength, pauseLength;
    Player player;

    public musicStuff() throws InterruptedException {
        // Calling Threads
        playThread = new Thread(runnablePlay);

        String response = "";
        while (!response.equals("Q")) {
            try {
                response = example.run("https://url webservice");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            switch (response) {
            case ("S"):
                if (flag_start < 1) {
                    playThread = new Thread(runnablePlay);
                    flag_stop = 0;
                    playThread.start();
                    System.out.println("Fai partire la musica");
                }
                flag_start = flag_start + 1;
                break;
            case ("N"):

                if (flag_stop < 1) {
                    flag_start = 0;
                
                    if (player != null) {
                        player.close();
                        playThread.stop();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Ferma la musica");
                }
                flag_stop = flag_stop + 1;

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Errore");
            }
        }

    }

    Runnable runnablePlay = new Runnable() {
        String audioFilePath = "AudioFileWithMp3Format.mp3";

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                File musicPath = new File(audioFilePath);
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(musicPath);
                bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
                player = new Player(bufferedInputStream);
                totalLength = fileInputStream.available();
                player.play();//starting music
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error occured during playback process:" + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

}
```

HelloWord.java

```
package hello;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        try {
            musicStuff clip = new musicStuff();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
}
```

I know that I used deprecated playThread.stop() but in this case for me is not a problem.
All works correctly :)